# Build Constrains Exclude all Go Files

Tags: go, frontend

I am following this tutorial for Front-End Golang work: https://dev.to/talentlessguy/let-s-write-frontend-in-go-6ch.

When installing the `GoDom` section, it cannot recognize this package (see image) and gives the following error:

```
main.go:4:2: build constraints exclude all Go files in D:\Go_Workspace\pkg\mod\github.com\siongui\godom@v0.0.0-20181006133514-8ba1cdb25192\wasm
```

I'm not sure how to recognize this package...any suggestions? Thanks.

**IDE:**

[image: IDE View]

Comment: Because the files names in the package end with `_js.go`, the files are excluded when the `js` build constraint is not specified.

Comment: You need to set variables GOOS=js and GOARCH=wasm

Comment: I'm not sure how to set the variables to GOOS=js and GOARCH=wasm. I tried typing them in the terminal and they still didn't change when I typed in 'go env'.